# File and folder permissions on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, permissions

I have deployed a simple Web Site on Windows Azure as a Web App.

Using ASP.NET, whenever a user clicks on a button, a file is created as `/hidden/test.txt`. I want the directory, and the file, to be hidden and protected from any user accessing the website.

Currently, if you type `www.sitename.com/hidden/test.txt` on your browser you can access and view the content of the file.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you considered using blob storage instead? In general the idea of storing something in file system of Web Site is neither reliable nor scalable.

Alternatively you can add custom rule to your web.config matching hidden/test.txt and returning custom Forbidden status, say. 
Or if used for testing you can give your file another extension not supported by current MIME mapping (e.g. test.xyz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Asp net App_Data folder is very secured so you can store your file in App_Data folder which could be use by the application but no any user can access from out side on url.("App_Data" is listed there as a restricted folder)

But on Azure Best practice is to store any file on Azure Storage Blob.

Related Link 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/